# Socket for canvas multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, canvas

i have problem with my js canvas game. project seems mad god game. (rotmg in google)
i use php socket to communication. when player change possition i send updated x and y:

```
function keysPressed(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;

    if (socket_open) {
        var msgg = {
            type : 'char_pos',
            px : pixX,
            py : pixY
        };

        websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msgg));
    }
}
```

server part:

```
//check for any incomming data
while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
{
    $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
    $msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
    $id=array_search($changed_socket,$clients);


        $pos[$id]['x']=$msg->px;
        $pos[$id]['y']=$msg->py;

    //prepare data to be sent to client
    $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'rys_inni', 'id'=>$id, 'pos'=>$pos)));
    send_message($response_text); //send data
    break 2; //exist this loop
}
```

next, when data come back i do this:

```
websocket.onmessage = function (ev) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data);
    var type = msg.type; 

    if (type == 'rys_inni') {
        tab_innych_charow = [];
        for (key in msg.pos)
            if (typeof(msg.pos[key]) !== 'undefined')
                tab_innych_charow.push(msg.pos[key]);

    }
};
```

and this is in interval:

```
function rysuj() {

// clear canvas and bckground

    for (i = 0; i < tab_innych_charow.length; i++) {

        var x = tab_innych_charow[i].x; // +...;
        var y = tab_innych_charow[i].y; // +...;

        draw(ctx, something, x, y);
    }
}
```

the problem is that the different players drawing with lags and my game look poor. 
where i do mistake ? is the problem lies in php? i read about socket.io but i would rather php cause it is easier for me, i think. in my model (realm of the mad god) move is very fast and smooth. i don't know what to do. you are my last chance. thanks.

Comment: so what is the problem? state it clearly.

Comment: i can't show You this, but background move is great, but when i try to draw other connected player(as black rect or something) it work but like 2 fps. like this second player have ping ~1000ms.. hard to explain, i think i'm a bad creator but this php spoil too.

Comment: possible mistake is to draw all moves on every frame, you should draw only 1 time on each frame, and messages do not have info about who made that move.